# build problems with SwiftOCR

Tags: swift, cocoapods, ocr

So I am trying to build and run an example program put out with SwiftOCR. After loading the pods needed and running build I get the attached screen shot error. I have no clue where to begin, can someone out there help? Thanks in advance.

[Screen shot from Xcode following build...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndROR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build and run the documentation.

Next to the stop (square) button, click "Documentation" and switch it to your app.

Comment: So is this the usual setting after pods are installed or is there a switch inside of CocoaPods that tweaks this setting and has it pointing to the correct file type once install is complete? The other question I would have is, if Xcode is pointing at the wrong file type (i.e. documentation), why wouldn't it create a much less cryptic error message? As you can tell I am pretty new to this language and compiler.

Comment: Perhaps it initially puts items in alphabetical order, but once you change it it keeps what you selected at the top. Looks like the project uses GPUImage and it could be that Brad (creator of GPUImage) just gitignored a shell file he used to build documentation, bc he figured nobody would need to build that.

Comment: @user6710871 did this answer your question? Mind accepting?